# How to join 2 fields in 1 in JSON with Ruby on Rails

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So i have this code in a JSON:

```
[ {
  "idema" : "0009X",
  "lon" : 0.963335,
  "fint" : "2022-05-03T13:00:00",
  "prec" : 0.0,
  "alt" : 406.0,
  "vmax" : 5.8,
  "vv" : 2.2,
  "dv" : 102.0,
  "lat" : 41.213894,
}}
```

And I want to get the fields `lat` and `long` and merge them like this in the JOSN:

```
  "longlat": "POINT(23.0 33.0)",
```

I'm parsing the file like this btw:

```
      meteo_station_list = JSON.parse(File.read('meteo_stations.json'))
      meteo_station_list.each do |station|
      MeteoStationAemet.create(station.to_h)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You need to Convert this Json to Hash

```rb
meteo_station_list = JSON.parse(File.read('meteo_stations.json')).with_indifferent_access
```

2- you just need to loop through the hash and use this snippet

```rb
def genrate_point 
  meteo_station_list.each do |station|
    station[:longlat] = "point(#{station[:lat]} #{station[:lon]}"
    station.except!(:lat,:lon)
  end
end
```

check [official except documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/except)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but I'm not able to understant how you link ```stations[lat]``` with lat in the json.

Comment: At the first step You converted the JSON to a Hash 
`station[:longlat]` this creates a new JSON key for you.
 `"point(#{station[:lat]} #{station[:lon]}"` this called string interpolation in ruby
After finish you should convert your Hash to a json then write it to your file